# How to plot a bar chart with bar values?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a bar char with python. Following is my code. I am getting `0` value for each of my bar.

```
from __future__ import division
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
freq = [0.93, 0.87,0.86,0.87,0.93,0.84,0.74,0.79,0.78,0.95,0.88,0.8, 0.71]

width = 0.5 # width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x, freq, width, color='r')

ax.set_ylim(0,1)
ax.set_ylabel('auc-roc')

ax.set_xticks(np.add(x,(width/2.2))) # set the position of the x ticks
ax.set_xticklabels(('X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'X6', 'X7', 'X8', 'X9', 'X10', 'X11', 'X12', 'X13'))

def autolabel(rects):

    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.0*height,
            '%d' % (height),
            ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)

plt.show()
```

[image: Image with 0 bar values]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'%d' % (height),
```

I think that this maps value to integer. In your case values are runded to `0`.

Use `%f` or rather `%.2f`.

[image]

Comment: That was just a change of format. Change `%d` to `%.2f` and it should work.